# PageSpeed module causes image break in Firefox mobile

Tags: android, ios, firefox, pagespeed, responsive

I have interesting problem with web which uses PageSpeed module. So when I enable PageSpeed images on the web are broken. Important thing is that it only occurs on Firefox on mobile devices (Android and iOS checked).

So, if PageSpeed is on:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pei292sz6qzswnb/2016-03-28%2011.09.10.png?dl=0

If PageSpeed is off:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aju6qxxdgeehtoa/2016-03-28%2011.10.05.png?dl=0

All other browsers on mobile device are working great and without a problem. Since PageSpeed gives me a good performance I wouldn't like to turn it off but this is just a big problem.

URL is http://ruhrgebietaktuell.de/

I have checked links, css styles, URLs...and no clue what to do next. Any help is highly appreciated.

Cheers!

P.s. Module is currently off but if anyone has an idea what to try I'll be more than glad to turn it on :)

Answer (score 0):

After my own research (with custom CSS, JSs, changing servers) it became clear that only two problems can be in Firefox or PageSpeed module.
Bug was reported to FF on
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1260203

On their recommendation hosting just provided this message...

> "we have just updated nginx, you have now version 1.9.10 with
>   Pagespeed 1.10.33.4-beta on your server."

Now everything works like a charm!

So, beware of nginx and PageSpeed module versions if you experience similar issue.

Thank you.